# Put dividers between share, edit, reopen, delete, and flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is hard to tell if three votes are to reopen this post or to delete it.
Or is it 1 vote to delete or 1 vote to flag?

[image]

If we placed dividers between these links it would make it so much easier...

```
share | edit | reopen (3) | delete (1) | flag
```

I request we add a light divider between each action.  This would tremendously help one see the counts correctly.

Comment: -1, not necessary IMO. For someone who's reached the rep threshold, it's easy enough to tell.

Comment: I'm not talking about experience / silly reputation threshold...we are talking about a UX change.  Better to be clear than to have any ambiguity, to each his own...you shouldn't rely on a rep threshold.  You should design based on what a person initially sees...if I opened a page like this: `share deleted (2) flag (3) reopen` how sure are you that the numbers point to the right action?  Are you going to base it on some sort of rep or usage of the tool or on how someone is telling you flat out they cannot tell?

Comment: They used to be there, but then the design team sacrificed them to the pixel gods...so I don't know how likely it is that they'll make a return.

Comment: I cannot understand why you'd get rid of something like that and it then can cause ambiguity.  Please rethink this decision design team.

Comment: I don't know about putting pipes there, but certainly an extra space would go a long way to improving clarity.

Comment: That's three votes _for_ deletion and one vote _against_. Pretty sure, anyways.

Comment: How about displaying like this: share edit reopen(3) delete(1) flag

Comment: Better.........But pipes are better

Comment: Pipes would be great - if it's a question of saving pixels for mobile viewing, you could use CSS media queries to show/hide them as needed.